# Массив с множеством key+value

Tags: c++, массивы

Мне нужен вектор, в который будут передаваться массивы с множеством ключей, это можно сделать через структуру:

```
struct logMess {
    logMess (string bn, string c, string n, string m) : 
        botName(bn), channel(c), name(n), message(m) { };
    string botName, channel, name, message;
};
vector<logMess> log;
log.push_back(logMess("q", "w", "e", "r"));
```

Но мне этот вариант не подходит, нужно обойтись без классов и структур. Такое возможно?

Comment: Почему этот вариант не подходит?

Comment: сделать вектор `std::tuple`'ов?

Comment: А как вы без классов и структур то обойдётесь ? У вас остаются примитивные типы (`int`,`char`,`double`, и т.д.) и указатели (или массивы) примитивных типов (`int*`, `char*`, `double*`). 
Можно json объекты там хранить в виде `std::string`, правда `std::string` тоже класс и вам понадобится библиотека для работы с  json (проще тогда уж std::vector< std::unordered_map<key, value> >. 
Или Вы под классами/структурами имели в виду пользовательские классы/структуры ?

Comment: @VTT потому, что преподаватель так хочет?

Comment: @alexolut естественно. Любая нестандартная задача означает, что тс делает уроки.

Comment: @Виталий любая необходимость должна как-то объясняться. Если Вы не желаете - приходится импровизировать.